# Android:Google maps coordinates

Tags: android, maps, coordinates

I have app which get coordinates and returned to the google maps.
I have just one problem.
When I put the coordinates,the Pointer is not very correct.
I have one method but I think is not for this job.

Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks in advance.

```
 touchedPoint=map.getProjection().fromPixels((int) cord,(int) cord1);

       CustomPoint custom = new CustomPoint(d, Maps.this);

        OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(touchedPoint, null, null);

         custom.insertPoints(overlayItem);
        overlayList.add(custom);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Google map v2. This has been deprecated and key been lost on March. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

And you can find tutorial in http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html